# Why I cannot assign $this by value, it aparently is assigned by reference always?

Tags: php, class, oop, object, pass-by-reference

The following code explains the problem I'm having, I'm trying to assign `$this` to a variable by value but it aparently is finally assigned by reference, why? and how can I do it?

The following script is a set of two classes `Test` and `TestQuery`. `Test` assumes a value in `$num` attribute, then the script calls `Test->exist()`, that creates two variables: `$original` "by value" and `$obj` by reference, at this point both are the same. Finally the script call `TestQuery->doit( $obj )`; is suposed that `TestQuery` will modify the `$code` of the `$obj` if the value of `$num` is 2, but the result is invalid, because the value of `$original` and `$obj` in `exist()` method is the same newly.

```
<?php

class TestQuery{
    public function doit( &$obj )
    {
        if ($obj->getNum() == 2)
            $obj->setCode( 55 );
    }
}

class Test {
    public $code;
    public $num;

    public function setCode( $code ) { $this->code= $code; }
    public function getCode( $code ) { return $this->code; }

    public function getNum()
    {
        return $this->num;
    }

    public function exist()
    {
        $original = $this;
        $obj =& $this;

        // The same objects ...(valid)
        echo "<xmp>";
        print_r( $original );
        echo " VS ";
        print_r( $obj );
        echo "</xmp>";

        $tc = new TestQuery();
        $tc->doit( $obj );

        // The same objects newly... (invalid, hoping different) 
        echo "<xmp>";
        print_r( $original );
        echo " VS ";
        print_r( $obj );
        echo "</xmp>";
    }

}

$t = new Test();
$t->num = 2;
$t->exist();

exit;

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is the use of `clone` keyword.

```
$original = clone $this;
```

Comment: For the explanation: an object is PHP is always assigned by reference. In java it is the case as well and PHP just copied the behavior.

The only way you have to copy the object is indeed to use clone.